# Prove $k^8 \geq (k^2 - 1)^4$ for $k \geq 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Can anyone please help me with following inequality:
$$k^8 \geq (k^2 - 1)^4, \text{where} \ k \geq 1.$$
I tried induction but get stuck at step $k=n+1$ and can't progress anywhere.

Comment: Why is there "probability"  among tags to this question?

Comment: I found it in probability textbook in exercise concerning with log-convexity. I will removed this tag, I realised it was wrong.

Comment: @econ After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 3):

factorizing $$k^8-(k^2-1)^4$$ we get $$\left( 2\,{k}^{2}-1 \right)  \left( 2\,{k}^{4}-2\,{k}^{2}+1 \right) \geq 0$$ and this is true for $$k\geq 1$$

Answer (score 3):

Since $k^8 = (k^2)^4$, we just need to show that (for $a,b\geq0$) $a\geq b \implies a^4 \geq b^4$. Indeed, if $a\geq b$, then $a-b\geq 0$, and so $a^4-b^4 = (a-b)(a^3+a^2b+ab^2+b^3) \geq 0$. Thus, $a^4 \geq b^4$.

Clearly, $k^2>k^2-1$, and so $k^8 > (k^2-1)^4$ since $k^2, k^2-1 \geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $k\geq1$, it's just $k^2\geq k^2-1$.

Answer (score 0):

As $k^8>0,$

$$k^8\ge(k^2-1)^4\iff\left(1-\dfrac1{k^2}\right)^4\le1$$

As $k\ge1,k^2\ge1\implies0<\dfrac1{k^2}\le1\iff0\le1-\dfrac1{k^2}<1$